# Version control system that shows current editors

Tags: version-control

I'm looking for a version control system like svn, git which
- can be used for software projects in Java, C++,
- can manage and show a list of all current editors of a version-controlled file who have not committed yet,
- and possibly more information like times and amount of changes.

This would probably need a supporting source code editor which (automatically) notifies the version control system when editing the file is started, or when changes are reverted.

Comment: With Git you could attempt to employ hooks to notify some service. But your reasoning seems to have flaws. For example if I clone from a clone, would you still see notification? Otherwise there would have to be some "authoritative" repo. What if I cloned from a bundle instead? Considering Git only what do you want to see? The fact that something has been touched? That something is in the index but not committed? That something is committed but not pushed? Differences thereof? Your question is akin to the "lock" model of old. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software